# How to split number and string inside list in python

Tags: python, list

I have list of data: `['66306 Mozambique', '63344 El Salvador', '60221 Singapore']`. I would like to split the numbers and string into this: `['66306','Mozambique','63344','El Salvador','60221 ','Singapore']`, is there any way to do it?

Comment: you could use `split()` if the elements are separated by space `[e for elt in x for e in elt.split()]`

Answer (score 1):

You might split at space once, which will result in list of lists:

```
lst = ['66306 Mozambique', '63344 El Salvador', '60221 Singapore']
lst = [i.split(" ", 1) for i in lst]
print(lst)
```

output:

```
[['66306', 'Mozambique'], ['63344', 'El Salvador'], ['60221', 'Singapore']]
```

Then you need to *flatten* it, for example using list comprehension as follows

```
lst = [item for subl in lst for item in subl]
print(lst)
```

output:

```
['66306', 'Mozambique', '63344', 'El Salvador', '60221', 'Singapore']
```

Keep in mind there are [many ways to flatten list](https://www.pythonpool.com/flatten-list-python/), so feel free to use another method if it fits your case better.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a join operation on the list and then split the list on spaces

```
input = ['66306 Mozambique', '63344 El Salvador', '60221 Singapore']

res = ' '.join(input).split(' ')

print(res)

#output =
['66306', 'Mozambique', '63344', 'El', 'Salvador', '60221', 'Singapore']
```